# Dependencies to CryptReleaseContext and other Advapi32 calls with Cgo

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mingw, cgo

I've a go binary(lets call A) using two dll's (B and C) via cgo. Both dll's are written with c++ and doesn't depend to any windows libraries so no explicit linking was done for any winapi dlls.

cgo uses migw 4.9.2 for its compilation.

Problem is; when I compile and run A, it fails to start saying "...CryptReleaseContext could not be located in the dynamic link library...".

From dependency walker I see;

only "B" -> depends to Advapi32.dll.

only "C" -> depends to Advapi32.dll.

"A" (the go executable)-> also depends to Advapi32.dll. And of course to B and C.

In this context of "A" when I click dependencies;

C -> has functions I really use is listed resolved. Advapi32.dll is **also** listed in dependencies with 3 functions listed as used in it. **but** CryptAcquireContextW, CryptGenRandom, CryptReleaseContext seems like unresolved functions on the level of library C.

B -> those three functions are not there listed at all but the real content is listed correctly.

So my question is; why those 3 winapi functions are seem like defined in library "C". As one in all of them when I check Advapi32.dll, I also see those 3 functions are defined in it and already used.

another question is, as they are c functions without mangling or decoration, why they cannot be found in the context of A.exe during runtime resolved from Advapi32.dll?

Since both B and C has very same compilation/linker flags I suspect here something about cgo.

following is the better view of above explanation. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
Dump of file A.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
Section contains the following imports:

ADVAPI32.dll
            9B0818 Import Address Table
            9B00F4 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference
B.dll
            9B0B20 Import Address Table
            9B0400 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                     54C correct_function_from_B
C.dll
            9B0EB8 Import Address Table
            9B0798 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      31 correct_function_from_C
                      DB CryptReleaseContext
                      D1 CryptGenRandom
                      C1 CryptAcquireContextW
```

`

Comment: Some of `dll`  problems disappear when using the same compiler for both `exe` and `dll` files.

Comment: For reference: http://mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers